# Print when espression - check if is empty array

Tags: java, jasper-reports

In JasperReport I want to print a field when it does not contain empty array.

How can I check it?

In "Print when expression" it is possible to write:

$F{myField} != null

but as $F{myField} is an empty array (so it is not null) it does not work.

Is there any method to check it? It seems to me that there is no isEmpty() function for JasperReport.

Comment: What is a type of `$F{myField}`?

Comment: It is an Object

Answer (score 0):

Try write something like:
`$F{myField}.length() == 0`

Comment: I found a solution.  !$F{myField}.toString().equals( "[]" ) works!